# Base 10 - Base 2 Converter in Java using a Stack

Tags: java, binary, stack, radix

I am not sure how close I am to end of this, but I have to create a program in Java using a Stack. I have the Stack class done, and now the only thing giving me issues is the Converter class. I am getting the following when I compile:

```
Base10Converter.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable rand
location: class Base10Converter

System.out.println(outputInBinary());
                                                      ^
1 error
```

I know it shouldn't be "rand," so that's just a place holder. Need help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Base10Converter
{
    public  static void Main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your base10 number: ");
        String in = scan.nextLine(); //read the value
        for (int x = 0; x < in.length(); x++)
        {
                if (in.charAt(x) >= 0 && in.charAt(x) <= 9)
                {
                        System.out.println(outputInBinary(rand));
                }
                else
                {
                System.out.println("Invalid Number! 0 - 9. No letters.");
                }
        }
    }//main

    public static void outputInBinary(int in)
    {
        CharStack cStack = new CharStack();
        while(in > 0)
        {
            int bit = in % 2;
            cStack.push((char)(bit + 48));
            if (cStack.isFull())
            {
                System.out.println("Stack is full!");
            }
            in = in/2;
        }
        while (!cStack.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println(cStack.pop());
        }
    }//ouputInBinary

}
```

EDIT: I took "rand" out as it's not what I am wanting (I had an idiot moment). What I want to print out is the result form the pop in the 2nd method. I want to be able to print the binary of the number the user entered.

Comment: What is the range of the random number you want?

Comment: Why don't you use [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is print out a void statement. 
Instead of `System.out.print(outputInBinary(int in));` to

```
outputInBinary((int)(Math.random()*100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a random object to generate a random number from 1 and 100 for example:

```
Random random = new Random();
rand = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read next line, [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) is a better fit here:

```
private static int readInt(Scanner scan) {
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        scan.next();
        System.out.println("Invalid Number! 0 - 9. No letters.");
    }
    return scan.nextInt();
}

public  static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your base10 number: ");
    outputInBinary(readInt(scan));
}
```